# Promise queues?

Tags: javascript, http, promise

I have an application that is sending a http request that returns a promise everytime the user types. I have it debouncing every 500ms. Sometimes the api I am requesting takes a long time to respond. For example, I make a search request for `a` that takes a long time to respond but then the user continues typing to complete the query of `a+x` which resolves almost immediately but the results of `a+x` get overridden by the previous request of just `a`.

TL;DR: if new promise is called before current resolves, how to cancel current

Comment: Code is worth 1024 words. Post a [mcve].

Comment: I'm using [vue-resource](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource) so I am trying to make this question as library/framework agnostic as possible to help other people.

Comment: _"which resolves almost immediately but the results of `a+x` get overridden by the previous request of just `a`"_ Why are results overwritten?

Comment: The results are overwritten because I am using a global state variable currently when the request resolves it gets set to the response.

Comment: You are going to need to use a Cancellable Promise. Which library are you using for making HTTP requests?

Comment: As mentioned in an above comment, [vue-resource](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource)

Comment: @ZucchiniZe _"The results are overwritten because I am using a global state variable currently when the request resolves it gets set to the response"_ Why overwrite the response? You could store all responses in an array or object and select response to display from array or object corresponding to index or property key of request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a variable that counts your requests:

```
var effectiveRequestNumber = 0;

function asyncRequest() {       
    var requestNumber = ++effectiveRequestNumber; // storing our request number
    doSomething().then(function(response) {
        // if the function was invoked after this request, then these two won't match
        if (effectiveRequestNumber !== requestNumber) {
            return;
        } 
        applyResponse(response); // we are fine - applying the response
    });
}
```

Comment: Yup, fundamentally the same as the one I wrote up. I tend to remember objects, but I've used both sequence numbers (like the above) and objects. Simple and effective.

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually handle overlapping queries where I only want the results of the last one is to remember something that I can check in the callback.

You haven't quoted any code which makes it tricky to help, but here's an example:

```js
"use strict";
// NOTE: Will only run if your browser supports promises.

// Scoping function to avoid globals
(function() {
  // We keep track of the most recent promise
  var lastSomethingRequest = null;
  
  // Our function that does something async
  function doSomething(value) {
    console.log("doing request for " + value);
    
    // Start the async, remember the promise
    var p = new Promise(function(resolve) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve("resolve for " + value);
      }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 500));
    });
    
    // Remember that as the most recent one
    lastSomethingRequest = p;
    p.then(function(result) {
      // Use the result only if it's the most recent
      if (lastSomethingRequest === p) {
        console.log("Use this result: " + result);
        lastSomethingRequest = null; // Release the promise object
      } else {
        console.log("Disregard outdated result: " + result);
      }
    });
  }

  // Generate 5 requests in a row that will complete in varying
  // amounts of time, where we only want the result of the last one
  for (var n = 0; n < 5; ++n) {
    doSomething(n);
  }
})();
```